# Why Android x86 9.0 boots in command line and not in GUI?

Tags: linux, command-line, android-x86

i just installed android x86 9.0c and i don't know why it doesn't boot on GUI mode and it boots only in commandline then after some seconds i can only see just a dash appearing and disappearing. I have tried to put my graphics settings to vboxvga and disabled 3D acceleration but it still doesn't work. What else i can do to fix this problem?

[here you can see that its booted in commandline , after some seconds it becomes black and all i can see is just a dash appearing and disappearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH9jh.png)

Answer (score 5):

This is a semi permanent fix. It will stay fixed until you open settings. Then you can just do it again.

**1.** On the main VBox screen in the display section click on what ever follows **Graphics Controller:**

**2.** In the box that opens select VBoxSVGA.

[image: Here is a picture of the main screen.]

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61247128) from Stack Overflow:

1. **Temporary fix**: append `nomodeset xforcevesa` at the end of the line containing kernel during boot time at the GRUB menu. During boot press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit. While on the line containing kernel press <kbd>E</kbd> again, append `nomodeset xforcevesa` at the end, press enter, then press <kbd>B</kbd> to boot.
2. **Permanent fix:** read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61247128).

Answer (score 0):

Using the 32bit version worked for me. Also try an older Android version